# invoke a domain method in a gsp

Tags: grails

I created a method in my domain class called `affichage(s)` that can retrieve the string between like `<name>` or `<adresse>`:

```
enter code here



def affichage(s){

def l=[]
def regex = /\<.\w*.\>/
def matcher = s =~ regex
matcher.each{match ->
l.add(match)}
l.each{ 
for (i in l){
println i
}}}}
```

I have run this function in groovyConsole and it's OK.

How do I invoke this method in my gsp to apply it in a textfield?

Comment: What does it need to return? Why collecting `Matches`, I believe you don't need `Matches`, but just `String`s?
Anyway, just pass an instance of your domain class as a Model part and call it from GSP. How exactly - depends on what do you need to do in your textfield, a GSP code sample would help.

Answer (score 5):

to do it the grails way, you would load the domain object in the controller, and then pass it to the view.  So something like the following in the controller:

```
// assuming theDomainObject/anotherObject are loaded, preferably via service calls
render view: 'theView', model: [object: theDomainObject, another: anotherObject]
```

and then in the view you can do

```
${object.yourMethod()}

${another.someprop}
```

note in the first you are invoking a method, in the next you are getting a property.  Also note that within the braces, you can reference the things you passed back on the model in the controller.  The

```
${...}
```

tells the gsp to use the model objects passed back.
grails is cool like that.

Answer (score 0):

To make the previous answer clear.

You don't pass the domain itself. You pass instance of the model as:

```
render(view: 'theView', model: [object: new MyDomain (), another: new YourDomain()]
```

Where MyDomain and YourDomain are domain classes in Grails.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a taglib like this...

```
// grails-app/taglib/com/demo/ParsingTagLib.groovy
package com.demo

class ParsingTagLib {
    static defaultEncodeAs = 'html'
    static namespace = 'parsing'

    def retrieveContentsOfTag = { attrs ->
        // The regex handling here is very
        // crude and intentionally simplified.
        // The question isn't about regex so
        // this isn't the interesting part.
        def matcher = attrs.stringToParse =~ /<(\w*)>/
        out << matcher[0][1]
    }
}
```

You can invoke that tag to populate the value of a text field from a GSP with something like this....

```
<g:textField name="firstName" value="${parsing.retrieveContentsOfTag(stringToParse: firstName)}"/>
<g:textField name="lastName" value="${parsing.retrieveContentsOfTag(stringToParse: lastName)}"/>
```

If that were rendered from a controller like this...

```
// grails-app/controllers/com/demo/DemoController.groovy
package com.demo

class DemoController {

    def index() {
        // these values wouldn't have to be hardcoded here of course...
        [firstName: '<Jeff>', lastName: '<Brown>']
    }
}
```

That would result in HTML that looks like this...

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" value="Jeff" id="firstName" />
<input type="text" name="lastName" value="Brown" id="lastName" />
```

I hope that helps.

**UPDATE:**

Depending on what you are really trying to do, you might also look at wrapping the whole text field generation thing up inside your tag with something like this...

```
// grails-app/taglib/com/demo/ParsingTagLib.groovy
package com.demo

class ParsingTagLib {
    static namespace = 'parsing'

    def mySpecialTextField = { attrs ->
        // The regex handling here is very
        // crude and intentionally simplified.
        // The question isn't about regex so
        // this isn't the interesting part.
        def matcher = attrs.stringToParse =~ /<(\w*)>/
        def value = matcher[0][1]
        out << g.textField(name: attrs.name, value: value)
    }
}
```

Then your GSP code could look like this...

```
<parsing:mySpecialTextField name="firstName" stringToParse="${firstName}"/>
<parsing:mySpecialTextField name="lastName" stringToParse="${lastName}"/>
```